# Determiner before the word - Demand

Tags: definite-article, indefinite-article, determiners

> They received a final demand for payment.
>
> The goverment is unlikely to agree to the rebel’s demands for
>   independence.

These sentences are from cambridge dictionary. In the second sentence, there is the definite article but could I use the zero article? I cant see any difference between these two sentences, but one is using the definite article and one not. Why?

Comment: The *the* in your second sentence modifies *rebel*, not *demands*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StoneyB is right about the *the* in your second example — it refers to the rebel. But you could take out "rebel's" and have the example you are trying to ask about: "The government is unlikely to agree to the demands for independence."

In one sense, the distinction between **a** and **the** here is just the normal one — if you said the government was unlikely to agree to *a demand* for independence, it would mean that no such demand had been given. But saying *the demand(s)* means that demands have been given. **A** is indefinite, and **the** is definite.

But in the first example, there's a bit more nuance. If you change it to "They received the final demand for payment," it would indicate that the demand was *expected,* even before it was given. Wording it this way indicates that the demand might have been a surprise, or at least that they weren't counting on receiving it.

Comment: And why is the article before rebel’s? Could I also omit it?

Comment: To be clear: I was saying that we could just remove the word _rebel's_ in order to clearly address your question. It definitely changes the meaning of the sentence, though. As far as whether you can remove the article before _rebel's,_ no, you really can't. Not with a singular _rebel,_ at least — you either need _a_ or _the_ before that. You could remove the article if it were _rebels'_ (plural), but then you'd be referring to any rebels that may or may not exist. The article _the_ has to be there in order to be clear that it's referring to a specific rebel.